# Disable Wordpress Sidebar in mobile view conditionally

Tags: wordpress, mobile, pagination, sidebar

I would like to disable my WP sidebar from within the template using something like the below, though I want to also conditionally disable it. Condition would be...when device width is max X, i.e. max-device-width: 720, or when pagination is on.

```
<?php if (wp_is_mobile() )
    {
    //do nothing
}
    else
    {
    < ? php get_sidebar(); ? >;
}
?>
```

The reason for the condition...on some mobiles (tablets), the sidebar is still present, not paginated, so I want it to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with CSS media queries. Put something like this in your style sheet:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    .wp_sidebar {
        display: none;
     }
}
```

And the sidebar will disappear if the page is 720px or less. I'd recommend against doing the mobile check on the server side, if that's a situation you can avoid.

Comment: Thanks @DocWatson. I was trying to get a server-side solution as I thought that approach would be better, and to avoid having to make any margin/padding adjustments. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Ah yes, having to make margin and padding changes can be a pain, but it's easier to deal with those than trying to send screen information to your server! Glad it worked out for you. This technique can help you dial in any other design consistencies you may come across. Good luck! [More on media queries from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)